# How should I make use of Network Namespaces to access two IDENTICAL WiFi AP?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

I encounter a problem when I'm trying to use a Ubuntu laptop computer to connect to two identical WiFi AP in the same time.

These two AP are actually not normal AP like broadband routers, but Sony consumer camera A6000. A6000 can work as a WiFi AP in order to accept connection and control from a mobile phone or tablet.

As far as I know, A6000's own IP address is fixed and can't be changed. As a result I failed to access (connection is OK, but control is not) two A6000 via two WiFi NICs in the same time because both of them have the same IP Address 192.168.122.1. I think Ubuntu's IP stack can't handle such scenario.

Here you can find more information about my problem:
https://serverfault.com/questions/728828/can-i-use-a-ubuntu-computer-to-connect-to-two-identical-wifi-ap

Therefore, now I'm considering to separate these two NICs to two different Network Namespaces. For example, route all communication 
to and from the 2nd WiFi NIC wlan1 to a virtual ethernet device which belongs to a new Network Namespace, while the 1st WiFi NIC wlan0 stays in the "global" one. If this is achievable, then the IP address conflict may be resolved.

As I'm new to Network Namespaces, I've find and studied many good tutorial about its basic concept from Internet. However, I still can't find any more specific one that is close to my target configuration described above. I'm wondering if there is any tutorial, document or book, that I can refer to as a starting point?

Any comment will be appreciated.